# jQuery DataTables Date Range Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I have a Partial View like so:

```
<div style="float: right;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
            <input id="Min-Date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="col-md-1 fa fa-minus text-center" style="margin-top: 1%;"></span>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
            <input id="Max-Date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





<table id="Test-Table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.randomClass.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Attachment)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot id="Table-Tfoot">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.randomClass.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Attachment)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.randomClass.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportDate)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Content(item.Attachment)" target="_blank">@Path.GetFileName(item.Attachment)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "tblAttachments", new { id = item.ID }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "tblAttachments", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) to get searching, paging, and sorting.  Here is my jQuery.

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

            var total = $("#Table tfoot th").length;

            $("#Table tfoot th").each(function (index) {
                if (index !== total - 1) {
                    var title = $(this).text().trim();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ' + title +'"/>');
                }
            });


            var table = $("#Test-Table").DataTable({
                "bFilter": false // hide searchbox
            });

            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change',
                    function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

As you can see I am hiding the initial search box that comes standard with jQuery datatables.. because I would like to be able to filter by **date-range**.

I have researched [this](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html), but I don't like how the boxes are above the paging dropdownlist.. so on mine.. the search box on the upper right is gone.. and I would like the two `input`'s to take it's place.  How can I do this via CSS?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: You may want to clarify your question. Are you asking how to modify the appearance of your table? Or are you asking how to sort by a date-range? And do you really want to sort by date-range? Usually you filter by date-range.

Comment: @klenwell I am asking how to modify the appearance of my table

Comment: it would help to have a sketch of how you want the datatable to look. We know what you don't want, but you haven't said where you want to position the drop-downs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this plunker demo
   Hope this makes you get your solution

http://plnkr.co/edit/mdeEYoZtnvpfHCdtSxDP?p=preview

```
$(function() {
  var oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter Data"
    },
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

  });




  $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
  });

  $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
  });

});

// Date range filter
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
      aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) can already show a data range, so i'm using it with the option: `inpput-daterange` which will take care of all the range-related things:

- the selected date range is clearly displayed with an alternate color
- clear buttons for the start date and end date are already built-in
- the input boxes are already aligned and styled as controlgroup

To align the record paging `select` of the DataTable, i'm moving it inside the Bootstrap column system, so it appears on top of the DataTable:

- the CSS to align the dropdown is just a matter of some top and left
  padding
- the Bootstrap column system can be easily configured for different screen width

Instead of disabling the search box, i would rather simply hide it:

- you can dynamically show and hide it, to switch between date-range
  filter and free-text search
- you can keep the standard search capabilities of the DataTable and
  use the sample provided in the [Documentation](https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) as it is

Here is the full example:

```js
var reportFilterRange = [null, null];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var date = Date.parse(data[1]);
      if (reportFilterRange[0] && date < reportFilterRange[0]) return false;
      if (reportFilterRange[1] && date > reportFilterRange[1]) return false;
      return true;
    }
  );

  var table = $("#Test-Table").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [3],
      "searchable": false
    }, {
      targets: [3],
      "orderable": false
    }]
  });
  $("#Test-Table_filter").css("display", "none");
  $(".dataTables_length").detach().appendTo('#lenContainer');

  $('#report-date-filter').on('changeDate', function(e) {
    var cases = ["Min-Date", "Max-Date"];
    reportFilterRange[cases.indexOf(e.target.id)] = Date.parse(e.date);
    table.draw();
  });

  $("#report-date-filter").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    clearBtn: true
  });

});
```

```css
#report-date-filter {
  max-width: 240px !important;
}

.dataTables_length {
  margin-left: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <div class="row" id="filterRow">
    <div id="lenContainer" class="col-xs-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="report-date-filter">
        <input id="Min-Date" type="text" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="Start Date" name="Min-Date" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input id="Max-Date" type="text" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="End Date" name="Max-Date" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table id="Test-Table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Class Name
        </th>
        <th>
          Report Date
        </th>
        <th>
          Attachment
        </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot id="Table-Tfoot">
      <tr>
        <th>
          Class Name
        </th>
        <th>
          Report Date
        </th>
        <th>
          Attachment
        </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>2017/07/25</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Tiger Nixon</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>2017/07/24</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Garrett Winters</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Ashton Cox</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Cedric Kelly</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Airi Satou</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Brielle Williamson</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Herrod Chandler</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Rhona Davidson</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Colleen Hurst</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Sonya Frost</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Jena Gaines</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Quinn Flynn</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Charde Marshall</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Haley Kennedy</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Tatyana Fitzpatrick</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Michael Silva</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Paul Byrd</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Gloria Little</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Bradley Greer</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Dai Rios</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Jenette Caldwell</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Yuri Berry</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Caesar Vance</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Doris Wilder</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Angelica Ramos</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Gavin Joyce</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Jennifer Chang</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Brenden Wagner</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Fiona Green</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Shou Itou</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Michelle House</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Suki Burks</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Prescott Bartlett</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Gavin Cortez</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Martena Mccray</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Unity Butler</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: yeah Perfect answer buddy i have been searched being a hours your answer is awesome

Comment: could please post code the date range and filter search at a time

Answer (score 1):

I have one suggestion you can have a look;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var total = $("#example tfoot th").length;

            $("#example tfoot th").each(function (index) {
                if (index !== total - 1) {
                    var title = $(this).text().trim();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ' + title +'"/>');
                }
            });


            var table = $("#example").DataTable({
                "bFilter": false // hide searchbox
            });

            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change',
                    function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    });
            });
} );
```

```css
tfoot input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .table-container{
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .filters {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    .datetimepicker{
      width: 180px;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px; 
    }
    .table-container .filters .form-control {
      height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-container">


<div class="filters">
        <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
            <input id="Min-Date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    
        <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
            <input id="Max-Date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
</div>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Also you can check in JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L9ma7xn5/
I dont suggest to use bootstrap cols here only put it with positioning your objects correctly with positive absolute and relative.

If theres any other questions refer freely.